# How to encrypt & decrypt multiple files to one file?

Tags: c#, encryption, compression, data-processing, file-structure

As title,
I want to encrypt 10 files into one file and the extension file can be customized. Once encrypted, I will automatically decrypt it to create 10 files as originally. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: The key question is how you were planning on doing it. What have you tried that isn't working and we can build from there? How will you define the boundaries of the various source files once they are in the single output file in order to accurately decrypt them? Are you going to encrypt them first then zip them etc.? More info is needed

Comment: Password protected zip or 7z file?

Comment: @Fabulous I'm looking for solutions so that when descypt we can have a sign that they divide into the original file.

Comment: @AdamG No, I will custom file extension, and not using zip or 7z in this case.

Comment: There is no requirement for a zip or 7z file to have .zip or .7z extension. Call it .Adam if you like.

Answer (score 1):

Just as any other stream where you can't discern messages, you need a delimiter of some sorts. Prepending the length of stuff is a common way to do so.

So make up a file format specification, for example:

- Start the file with an `uint32` which specifies the number of files in the archive
- Then, per file:

  - Write an `uint32` specifying the file name length in bytes in the encoding you want to use (I'd go for UTF-8)
  - Write the file name's bytes
  - Write an `uint32` specifying the file data length
  - Write the file data

Then when reading the file, read the uints and extract the next bytes.

But you generally don't want to invent your own file format.

Comment: Thanks, but if the user gives me the file with data.enc (sample data) and how can I split them into multiple files? Because I do not know the sign (the length of each file, and how many files are there?).

Comment: Yes you do, because you wrote that into the file when creating it.

Answer (score 0):

Possbile solution

- Encrypt all the files
- Store the encrypted data (`byte[]`) in a `List<byte[]>` or store it separatly in temp-files (maybe file.oldext.newext.tmp)
- Create a new XML file, write all the data to it (create a list within the XML file and store the data in the list elements; One element per file)
- Save the XML file to the disk (newfilename.newext)

Comment: Oh thanks, but how I can read this file (newfilename.newext)?.You mean: replace .newext, and it will be come newfilename.xml?!

Comment: XML files do not have to be in format <filename>.xml. They also can be <filename>.<anyextensionyouwant>
Just have to implement that in your code to read it as an xml file.
Decryption also is by reading XML, separating the items and decrypting them.

Comment: Oh. Thank you very much!